# Objective-C Blocks Error

Tags: objective-c, gcc, objective-c-blocks, gnustep

I just start learning Objective-C. I got an error when trying to make very small Objective-c Block example. It always shows "expected identifier or '(' before '^' token" errors?. COULD YOU PLEASE TELL ME WHERE DID I MAKE WRONG?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Block:NSObject
 - (void) printAdd;
@end

@implementation Block   
    void (^addition) (int, int)  =  ^(int left, int right) {
        NSLog(@"Total is: %d\n", left + right); 
    };

  -(void) printAdd {
       NSLog(@"Test");
        addition(12, 13);
    }
@end

int main() {
      Block* myBlock = [[Block alloc] init];
      [myBlock printAdd];
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "official" GCC does not support Objective-C blocks, compare [Are Objective-C blocks supported by compilers on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644814/are-objective-c-blocks-supported-by-compilers-on-linux), so you should use clang. You also need clang to take advantage of other
Objective-C features like "Automatic Reference Counting".

---

*Old answer:* That is valid Objective-C code.

My guess: You compiled that as a C program (main.c). Renaming the source file to main.m
should solve the problem.

Note that generally, `main()` for a Objective-C/Foundation program should establish an
"autorelease pool":

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
      Block* myBlock = [[Block alloc] init];
      [myBlock printAdd];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will get that code if you create a new "Commmand Line Tool" in Xcode and choose
"Type = Foundation".

Comment: :( It could not fix problem

Comment: @Binngokute: I have created a new project in Xcode from the "Command Line Tool" template, with "Type = Foundation", and copied your code into main.m. That compiled without problems.

Comment: @Binngokute: Which compiler do you use? gcc or clang? gcc does not support blocks, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/4645370/1187415.

Comment: gcc, not many document say that gcc does not support blocks. Thank so much for your help!